# android and sockets

Tags: android, sockets

I write client-server appliaction. Client is on android, server on plain Java. I want to client make connection with server next send him some file then server write this file on server-disc and then send to client another file. For now client make connection then send file to server but here starts problems. When I want to server send file to client I get "socket is close" exception.

Here is my code:

server:

```
public class ThreadHandler implements Runnable
{
public ThreadHandler(Socket i)
{ 
    sk = i; 
}

public void run()
{  
    try
    {
        File file = getFile();
        ParseData data = parseXML(file);

        if(data.getEvent().equals("registration"))
        {
            sendRegistrationResponse();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public File getFile() throws Exception
{
    File file=null;

    InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();

    file = new File("C://protocolFile/" + "temp.xml");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getReceiveBufferSize()];

    int bytesReceived = 0;

    while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0) {
        out.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
    }

    input.close();
    input = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
    System.gc();

    return file;
}

public void sendRegistrationResponse() throws Exception
{
    String fileName = createRegistrationResponseXML();
    sendToApp(fileName);
}

public void sendToApp(String fileName) throws Exception
{
    OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();     

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getSendBufferSize()];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
    }

    output.close();
    fileInputStream.close();
}

}
```

client:

```
public class AndroidProtokolActivity extends Activity {

private File directory;

XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();;

Socket sk;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "protocol");
    directory.mkdirs();
}

public void fun(View view)
{
    Log.i("======", "fun==============");
    try
    {
        sk = new Socket("55.555.555.555", 5555);

        String registrationFile = createRegistrationXML(serializer);
        sendToServer(registrationFile,sk);
        getRegistrationXML();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendToServer(String file, Socket sk) throws Exception
{
    Log.i("======", "sendToServer==============");
    OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();     

    String pathToOurFile = directory + File.separator + file;

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToOurFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getSendBufferSize()];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
    }

    output.close();
    fileInputStream.close();
}

public File getRegistrationXML() throws Exception
{
    Log.i("======", "getRegistrationXML==============");
    File file=null;

    InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();

    file = new File(directory, "rejestracjaOdpowiedz.xml");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getReceiveBufferSize()];

    int bytesReceived = 0;

    while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0) {
        out.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
    }

    input.close();
    input = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
    System.gc();

    return file;
}
}
```

I cut from this code creating XML files functions. I get "java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed" on line "OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();" in function "sendToApp" on server side and "java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed" on line "InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();" in "getRegistrationXML" line in function "getRegistrationXML" on client side. I try to find out what is wrong but I dont have any idea. Do anyone of you know what is wront with this code?  Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

This code show how I create XML file:

```
public String createRegistrationXML(XmlSerializer serializer) throws Exception
{
    Log.i("======", "createRegistrationXML==============");
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    writer = new StringWriter();
    serializer.setOutput(writer);

    serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("", XMLTag);
            serializer.startTag("", eventTag);
                serializer.text(REGISTRATIONEVENT);
            serializer.endTag("", eventTag);
        serializer.endTag("", XMLTag);
    serializer.endDocument();

    File outputFile = new File(directory, "file.xml");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos); 
    osw.write(writer.toString());
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();

    return "file.xml";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to close the socket's input and output stream individually. Just close the *socket* when all is done.

Comment: I delete every close funcion on streams and now server stuck in "while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0) {
   out.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
  }" on "getFile" function, but client stuck in function "getRegistrationXML". Its looks like (bytesReceived = input.read(buffer) is always > 0. Please check how I create XML file in edit in my first post. Maybe there is my problem.

Comment: That's correct: The *read* operation on the socket will block until data is received. It cannot know when all data is received. You probably need a way to signal the end of data to the receiver so that it stops reading and starts to send.

Comment: I notice that when I have line "output.close();" in "sendToServer"
on client side server dont stuce. Do you know what its mean?

Comment: Yes. When one side closes the connection, the other side will be notified and read will return end of stream (-1). From then on, though, you have a "half-open connection" which may cause those "closed" exceptions.

Comment: Any idea how can I signal the end of data to the receiver?

Comment: Depending on your protocol, you can a) send the length of the data first or b) send some special end of data token after the data or c) detect when the received XML document has ended (last tag closed). (Feel free to *accept* my answer :))